# react-router-dom - the Path in LinkAnchor Tag cannot be isolated out when users click on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a button that navigates user to a new tab and new path.
But somehow the path specified in the LinkAnchor tag cannot be isolated from the original path.
How can I direct users to the right path?

- For example, the button is on below page with path:
  'http://localhost:3000/workspace/test1ws/video/rooms'
  with Link tag:

  ```
  <Button onClick={()=>handleConferenceClick({item})}>
   <Link to ={item.video_room_url} target ='_blank'>
        Join meeting
   </Link>
  <Button>
  ```

  when I click on the button, the new tab with following routes pops up:
  'http://localhost:3000/workspace/test1ws/video/https://meet.jit.si/de1d6388be'

  what I intended for the route:
  'https://meet.jit.si/de1d6388be'

The child-parent component structure is :
DashboardContainer.js -> VideoContainer.js -> VideoJoinRoom.js

Thank you in advance for the opinions and help!

The code in VideoJoinRoom.js:

```js
 const VideoConferenceRoom = ({currentWorkspace, handleClick}) => {
 const [currentVideoRoom, setCurrentVideoRoom] = useState([]);

        useEffect(()=>{
            
            const getVideo = async()=>{
                const body = {currentWorkspace};
                    try{
                        const getVideoInfo = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/workspace/${currentWorkspace}/video/rooms`,{
                            method:"POST",
                            headers: {
                                "Content-Type":"application/json",
                                "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token")
                            },
                            body: JSON.stringify(body)
                        })
                        const response = await getVideoInfo.json();
                        //the ...response.videoRooms allows you to access each element in the array that is returned
                        setCurrentVideoRoom([...response.videoRooms])
                        console.log(response.videoRooms.video_room_pw); 
                        // console.log(currentVideoRoom);
                        
                    }catch(e){
                        console.error(e.message);
                    }
                }
            getVideo();
            // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
        },[]);

        const handleConferenceClick = (item)=>{
            handleClick(item)
        }

        /**Styling */
        const useStyles = makeStyles((theme)=>({
            /**Cards */
            cardLayout:{
                width: '6rem',
                padding: '0.5rem'
            },

            /**Typography */
            typographyMargin: {
                margin: '1rem'
            },

            /**Table */
            tableContainer: {
                margin: '1rem'
            }
        }));
        const classes = useStyles();

        return currentVideoRoom&&currentVideoRoom.length>1?(
        <>
             <Typography
             variant='h3'
             className = {`${classes.typographyMargin}`} 
             >
                 Join the video meetings happening in this workspace!
            </Typography>
            <Grid
            container
            direction='row'
            spacing = {2}
            >
                <TableContainer
                className = {`${classes.tableContainer}`}
                >
                            <TableHead>
                    {currentVideoRoom.map((item) => (
                        <TableRow>
                                <Grid
                                container
                                direction='column'
                                alignItems = 'center'
                                >
                                            <Card
                                            className = {`${classes.cardLayout}`}
                                            >
                                            Room {item.id}
                                            </Card>
                                         </Grid>
                                        <TableCell>
                                            <Typography>
                                                Room name: 
                                            </Typography>
                                            <Typography>
                                            {item.video_room_name}
                                            </Typography>
                                        </TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>
                                        Room password(use this password to join the meeting!) : {item.video_room_pw}
                                        </TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>
                                        Room url: {item.video_room_url}
                                        </TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>
                                        <Button onClick={()=>handleConferenceClick({item})}>
                                        {/* <Link to ={`/workspace/${currentWorkspace}/video/rooms/join`}> */}
                                        <Link to ={item.video_room_url} target ='_blank'>
                                            Join meeting
                                        </Link>
                                        </Button>
                                        </TableCell>
                                    </TableRow>

                    ))}
                </TableHead>
                </TableContainer>
            </Grid>
         </>
    ):(
                    <h1>No video meetings now.</h1>
    )


    export default VideoConferenceRoom;
```

If it helps, this is the Routes in VideoContainer:

```
  <Route
      path={`/workspace/${currentWorkspace}/video/rooms/join`}
      render={(props)=><VideoJoinRoom {...props} userName={userName} currentWorkspace={currentWorkspace} url={joinRoomUrl} pw={joinRoomPw} roomName={joinRoomName}/>}  
      exact
      />
    <Route
          path={`/workspace/:${currentWorkspace}/video`}
          render={(props)=><VideoCreateRoom {...props} userName={userName} currentWorkspace={currentWorkspace}/>}
          exact
          />
    <Route 
          path={`/workspace/${currentWorkspace}/video/rooms`}
          render={(props)=><VideoConferenceRoom handleClick ={handleVideoJoinClick} {...props} currentWorkspace={currentWorkspace}/>}  
          exact
          />
```

This is the code from Dashboard Container:

```js
function DashboardContainer() {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [userWorkspaces, setUserWorkspaces] = useState([]);
  const [currentWorkspace, setCurrentWorkspace] = useState("");
  const [isAdmin, setAdmin] = useState(false);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [firstEmptyUsers, setFirstEmptyUsers] = useState([]);
  const [allWorkspaces, setAllWorkspaces] = useState([]);
  const [chatroomId, setChatroomId] = useState("");
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState("");
  const [loginUsers, setLoginUsers] = useState([]);


  const chatroomInit = (workspace) => {
    console.log("chatroomInit receive", workspace);
    try {
      Axios.post(
        "http://localhost:4000/workspace/chatroominit",
        // Axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_SERVER}/workspace/chatroominit`,
        {
          workspaceName: workspace,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
          },
        }
      ).then((res) => {
        console.log("chatroominit", res);
        console.log("chatroom Id", res.data);
        setChatroomId(res.data);
      });
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  const getUserWorkspaces = () => {
    try {
      Axios.get("http://localhost:4000/workspace/list", {
        // Axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_SERVER}/workspace/list`, {
        headers: {
          "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      }).then((res) => {
        // console.log(`all workspaces`);
        // console.log(res);
        console.log("this is userworkspaceSS", res.data.allWorkspaces);
        setUserWorkspaces(res.data.userWorkspaces);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  const getUserInfo = () => {
    try {
      Axios.get("http://localhost:4000/username", {
        // Axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_SERVER}/username`, {
        headers: {
          "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      }).then((res) => {
        setUserId(res.data.id);
        setUserName(res.data.userName);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  const getCurrentWorkspace = () => {
    const path = window.location.pathname;
    // console.log(`url is below`);
    // console.log(path);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    const regex = /\/workspace\/([^\/]+)/;
    const result = path.match(regex);
    // console.log(`currworkspace url is below`);
    // console.log(result);
    const currWorkspace = result[1];
    console.log("currWorkspace value", currWorkspace);
    chatroomInit(currWorkspace);
    setCurrentWorkspace(currWorkspace);
    //send post request to server and check if user is admin
    checkIfAdminUsers(currWorkspace);
  };

  const getAllWorkspaces = () => {
    try {
      Axios.get("http://localhost:4000/workspace/all", {
        // Axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_SERVER}/workspace/all`, {
        headers: {
          "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      }).then((res) => {
        // console.log(`res from workspace/all`);
        // console.log(res);
        setAllWorkspaces(res.data);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  const checkIfAdminUsers = (workspace) => {
    try {
      //1. send post request to server, query to "user_workspace" table
      Axios.post(
        "http://localhost:4000/workspace/check",
        // `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_SERVER}/workspace/check`,
        {
          workspaceName: workspace,
        },
        {
          headers: { "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token") },
        }
      ).then((res) => {
        // console.log(`Getting post request in /workspace/check`);
        // console.log(res);
        setAdmin(res.data.isAdmin);
        setUsers(res.data.allUsers);
        setFirstEmptyUsers(res.data.firstEmptyUsers);
      });
      //2. check if that user is the workspace_admin, return the workspace_admin boolean
      //3. if yes, that user can have the right to assign task, and can see the create task UI
      //4. if no, that user can only see all the tasklists in that workspace
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  const postLogout = () => {
    try {
      Axios.post(
        "http://localhost:4000/checkloginusers",
        {
          userName: "",
        },
        {
          headers: { "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token") },
        }
      ).then((res) => {
        console.log("Current login users from '/checkloginusers'");
        console.log(res.data.loginUsers);
        const currentLoginUsers = res.data.loginUsers;
        console.log(currentLoginUsers);
        setLoginUsers(currentLoginUsers);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserWorkspaces();
    getUserInfo();
    getCurrentWorkspace();
    getAllWorkspaces();
    postLogout();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Grid
        container
        direction="row"
        alignItems="stretch"
        className={`${DashboardContainerCss.containerHeight} ${DashboardContainerCss.containerBackground}`}
        
      >
        <Router>
          <DashboardProfileSidebar
            name={userName}
            workspaces={userWorkspaces}
          />
          <DashboardFeatureSidebar
            currentWorkspace={currentWorkspace}
            userId={userId}
            chatroomId={chatroomId}
          />
          <Grid
            Container
            direction="row"
            md={9}
            spacing={0}
            alignItems={"flex-end"}
            className = {DashboardContainerCss.overrideGrid}
          >
            <DashboardNavbar loginUsers={loginUsers} userName={userName} />
            {/* <Switch> */}
            {/* for profile route */}
            <Route 
            exact
            path="/profile" component={DashboardProfileHome} />
            {/* <Route path="/profile/find" component={DashboardAddSocial} /> */}
            <Route
              path="/profile/create"
              render = {()=>
              <DashboardCreateWorkspace />
            }
            />
            <Route 
              path="/profile/search"
              render = {()=>
                <DashboardSearchWorkspace allWorkspaces={allWorkspaces} />
            }
            
            />
            {/* </Route> */}
            {/* for workspace route */}
            <Route
              exact
              path={`/workspace/:${currentWorkspace}/chat`}
              component={ChatroomContainer}
            />
            <Route
              path={`/workspace/:${currentWorkspace}/docs`}
              component={CollabNoteContainer}
            />
            <Route
              path={`/workspace/:${currentWorkspace}/dropbox`}
              component={DropboxContainer}
            />
            <Route
              path={`/workspace/:${currentWorkspace}/tasks`}
              render={(props) => (
                <CollabTaskContainer
                  {...props}
                  isAdmin={isAdmin}
                  users={users}
                  name={userName}
                  firstEmptyUsers={firstEmptyUsers}
                />
              )}
            ></Route>
            <Route
              path={`/workspace/:${currentWorkspace}/calender`}
              component={CalenderContainer}
            />
            <Route
              path={`/workspace/:${currentWorkspace}/whiteboard`}
              component={WhiteboardContainer}
            />
            <VideoContainer
              currentWorkspace={currentWorkspace}
              userName={userName}
            />
            {/* </Switch> */}
          </Grid>
        </Router>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}

export default DashboardContainer;
```

This is what I found on react-dev-tool:
the props and rendering of that LinkAchor :

```
{
  "target": "_blank",
  "children": "Join meeting",
  "href": "/workspace/test1ws/video/https://meet.jit.si/e29e358774",
  "navigate": "ƒ navigate() {}"
}

rendered by 
Router.Consumer
Link
VideoConferenceRoom
Router.Consumer
Route
VideoContainer
DashboardContainer
Router.Consumer
Route
App
createLegacyRoot()
react-dom@17.0.1
```